# I need help figuring out how to change values in a dataframe column to a value in another dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, dataframe

I have 2 tables of data.  Table 1 is called TERMS and contains three columns: P_TERM, STRESC, and CATEGORY. It looks like this:
    P_TERM       STRESC   CATEGORY
    __________   _______  ________
    Discolored   Stained  Hair
    Discolored   Stained  Skin

The second table contains 4 columns and is called FINDINGS.  It looks like:
    SPECIES  STRAIN  STRESC   CATEGORY
    _______  ______  _______  _________
    Rat      Wistar  Stained  Hair
    Dog      Beagle  Stained  Skin

I'm reading both tables into dataframes.

I need to replace every value of FINDING in the FINDINGS dataframe with the P_TERM value from the TERMS dataframe by comparing the values of STRESC and CATEGORY in the 2 dataframes and retrieving the P_TERM value from the TERMS dataframe.

so after the process the FINDINGS table would look like:

```
SPECIES  STRAIN  STRESC     CATEGORY
_______  ______  ______     _________
Rat      Wistar  Discolored Hair
Dog      Beagle  Discolored Skin
```

I'd like to do this without iterating through the thousands of rows in the FINDINGS dataframe.  Using the value 'UNMAPPED" when no match is found.

I've tried the following:

```
s = terms.drop_duplicates(subset=['STRESC', 'DATATYPE']).set_index(['STRESC', 'CATEGORY'])['P_TERM']
findings['STRESC'] = findings.loc[:,['STRESC', 'CATEGORY']].map(s).fillna('UNMAPPED')
```

But I'm obviously not using the map function correctly.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use pandas `merge` to merge the dataframes based on category and then select whatever columns you want to keep. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

```
findings = findings.merge(terms, on='CATEGORY')
```